# How to run Adobe flash player in 2022

Tags: flash, virtual-machine, adobe

We have an administrator panel that was created with use of Adobe flash player technology. Source code is proprietary/closed. System cost huge amount of money so it won't be recreated with use of new technologies.

Nowadays Adobe flash player is not supported with Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

Is there any way to use Adobe flash player in 2022?

Possibly some legacy software like Windows 7 x32 (or Ubuntu), Firefox 85 and Adobe flash player could be installed on a virtual machine?

Where such old software versions could be found?

Comment: Is it mandatory for this tool to be run in browser? Because you can build (it could take like 15 minutes if you know what are you doing) an empty AIR shell that loads your tool and allows it to run as a system application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use not supported Adobe Flash Player I performed following steps:

1. Create a virtual machine with `x32 CPU` (not current `x64 CPU`).
2. Install **Windows 7 SP1 x86**
3. Install **Firefox portable 81.0.1** from https://portableapps.com
4. Install **Adobe Flash Player Firefox** from https://filehorse.com
5. Restart virtual machine.

It works like a charm!